# Copying worksheets from multiple workbooks into one workbook pasting to the right

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate some help right now.

I am trying to take a range of cells `F37:F53` from `Sheet1` of multiple workbooks and paste it into `Sheet1` of a new workbook. The one issue I am having is that all the data pastes down in one column. What I actually want is each set of data to paste to the column to the right. So in other words `F37:F53` of workbook 1 should be pasted into `A1` of the final workbook. Then `F37:F53` of workbook 2 should be pasted into `B1` of the final workbook. So on and so forth with a limit of 365 columns

I would really appreciate some help as I am fairly new to VBA

Thank you in advance!

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\a0086850\Documents\421\2017")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("F37:F53" & Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017").Activate

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the FSO bit is right, try this

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()

Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\a0086850\Documents\421\2017")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
    c = c + 1
    bookList.Sheets(1).Range("F37:F53").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017").Cells(1, c)
    bookList.Close
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just something you need quick I suggest RDBMerge.  A fantastic tool for merging workbooks/worksheets.  [RDBMerge](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm)